# merging two xml elements uning XSLT

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have a large xml file like below

```
:
:
<CN>222</CN>
<CT>Raam</CT>
:
:
```

I would like to merge these two elements as

```
<CN>222 Raam</CN>
```

then like to convert it as

```
<div>222 Raam</div>
```

which is the final output.

Comment: Without more context nobody can help you. Please show the input XML and your XSLT.

Comment: I'm using below XSLT                                   <xsl:variable name="xx"  select="CT"></xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="CN">
  <div class="chap-title"><span><xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:copy-of select="$xx"/></span>
  </div>
</xsl:template>

Answer (score 1):

Well if all you need is merging the two consecutive elements in a `div` (I don't understand what the intermediary `CN` is for) then use

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CN[following-sibling::*[1][self::CT]]">
  <div>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' ', following-sibling::*[1][self::CT])"/>
  </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CT[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::CN]]"/>
```